# Question on differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Let $u,v,w$ be functions of $t$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, which are 3 times differentiable.

$u'''=\begin{cases}\,\,\,\,2,\,\,u<v,w\\-1,\,\,otherwise\end{cases}$

$v''',w'''$ are similarly determined.

Now consider an IVP. Given $u,v,w,u',v',w',u'',v'',w''$ at $t=0$, with $u\neq v\neq w\neq u$, can there exist $c>0$ s.t. $\forall t>c,u(t)=v(t)=w(t)$?

(Here we consider the solution of this ODE as caratheodory-solution.)

Comment: You'll need to specify your notion of solution to an ODE whose right side is a discontinuous function of the state vector. There are some out there (e.g. Caratheodory solution) but you need to say which one it is.

Comment: @lan - As you said, we may consider the solution as caratheodory-solution.  (Thanks for your comment.)